# Quickbooks Http Web Request code gives 400 Server error

Tags: asp.net, .net, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am using Quickbooks V3 SDK.It was also giving 400 error as In October 2014 they had changed their link from https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/ to sandbox.quickbooks.api.intuit.com/, after correcting I can fetch results and can perform crud operations using its mentioned classes.

```
 ServiceContext serviceContext = getServiceContext(profile);
            serviceContext.IppConfiguration.BaseUrl.Qbo = "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/";
            QueryService<Item> ItemQueryService = new QueryService<Item>(serviceContext);
            return ItemQueryService.Select(c => c).ToList();
```

This code works perfectly.

But when i try to perform the same operation as JSON request with HTTP web request, it gives me 400 error.
I am pasting HTTP Web request code below.

> ```
> HttpContext.Current.Session["serviceEndPoint"] = "https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/" + profile.RealmId +"/item&query=select * from item"; //
>         OAuthConsumerContext consumerContext = OAuthCR();
>
>         OAuthSession oSession = OAuthSession(consumerContext);
>
>         oSession.ConsumerContext.UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true;
>
>         oSession.AccessToken = new TokenBase
>         {
>             Token = profile.OAuthAccessToken,
>             ConsumerKey = "qyprdB0F3beIfmSTdvpLG5J46xPGm2",
>             TokenSecret = profile.OAuthAccessTokenSecret
>         };
>
>
>         IConsumerRequest conReq = oSession.Request();
>
>         conReq = conReq.Post();
>         conReq.AcceptsType = "application/json";
>         conReq = conReq.ForUrl(HttpContext.Current.Session["serviceEndPoint"].ToString());
>
>
>         string header = conReq.Context.GenerateSignatureBase();
>
>
>         try
>         {
>             string res = conReq.ReadBody();
>
>         }
>         catch (WebException we)
>         {
>             HttpWebResponse rsp = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
>             if (rsp != null)
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream()))
>                     {
>                         string res2 = rsp.StatusCode + " | " + reader.ReadToEnd();
>
>
>                     }
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception)
>                 {
>                     string res = "Status code: " + rsp.StatusCode;
>                 }
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 string res = "Error Communicating with Mock Service" + we.Message;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

They have mentioned wrong url on their sdk which is https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/xxxxxxxxx/
but correct one is
https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/xxxxxxxxxx/